# Laravel admin panel for existing project

Tags: php, laravel, admin

I am now developing a project with Laravel 5.4
I need to add an Admin Panel over this existing project, but from what I see, there are quite few options for that.
One option is [AdminLTE](https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel), but documentation on installing over existing project is very undetailed.
It also requires me to delete default Laravel Auth Controller, which is really not an option for me, because I've done a lot of changes in it.

Can you please recommend any admin panel that would be easy to install on existing project ?
Or should I write it myself ? But I'm not sure I can handle it.

Comment: AdminLTE is just a CSS theme - why don't you just integrate it yourself? That way you don't need to remove any existing functionality. https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html

Answer (score 2):

i can recommend you a voyager package for laravel 5

```
step:1 composer require tcg/voyager

step:2 set up your .env file

step:3 put following 2 line in your app.php
TCG\Voyager\VoyagerServiceProvider::class,
Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,

step:4 php artisan voyager:install

step:5 run your migration ->  php artisan migrate
```

and then go to

```
localhost:8000/admin
```

or whatever your server is

Comment: Does anyone know if this can be done on an existing Laravel project - will it break anything?

Answer (score 1):

Here I would recommend you to adopt a Laravel admin panel which I am using it already. That was the best Admin template which I've seen in recent days. Name of the product is Josh and available on Codecanyon.

Here is the link of the product where you can get it

https://codecanyon.net/item/josh-laravel-admin-template-front-end-crud/8754542?s_rank=9

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to follow the installation instruction provided by `AdminLTE`. As its a frontend template, just copy the `css` and `js` files of `AdminLTE` to your Laravel's `public` folder. Then take the html pages that you need from `AdminLTE`. You need to update the `css` and `js` links of that html with the new path of those file in your Laravel(use `asset` method).

Answer (score 0):

Supposition: You are with Laravel 5.4

Add admin-lte Laravel package with:

```
 composer require "acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel:4.*"
```

To register the Service Provider edit config/app.php file and add to providers array:

Acacha AdminLTE template provider

```
Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Providers\AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider::class,
```

To Register Alias edit config/app.php file and add to alias array:

Acacha AdminLTE template alias

```
'AdminLTE' => Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\Facades\AdminLTE::class,
```

Finally Publish files with:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=adminlte --force
```

Use force to overwrite Laravel Scaffolding packages. That's all! Open the Laravel project in your browser or homestead machine and enjoy!